# If $f(f(x))=x$, find a way to compute $x$ depending on the given $f(x)$

Tags: linear-algebra

I recently came across the following problem: Find all solutions to the following equation: $(x^2+7x+6)^{2}+7(x^2+7x+6)+6=x$

I first noticed that if we let $f(x)=x^2+7x+6$ then the given equation just simplifies to $f(f(x))=x$ but I was not sure of how to use that fact to solve the question and just ended up monotonously bashing it out to get the values of $x$. I did get the question correct but I was wondering if there is a nicer way of doing this problem by using the fact that $f(f(x))=x$. The values of $x$ are $-4\pm\sqrt{2},-3\pm\sqrt{3}$.

Source: Duke Math Meet 2007 Individual Round Problem 7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$f(f(x))-x$ is obviously divisible by $f(x)-x$ (i.e. a fixed point of $f$ is also a fixed point of $f \circ f$).  The quotient turns out to be $x^2 + 8 x + 14$.  The answers are thus the roots of $x^2+6x + 6$ and the roots of $x^2 + 8 x + 14$.

Slightly more generally, for any monic quadratic $f(x) = x^2 + a x + b$, 
$$ \dfrac{f(f(x))-x}{f(x)-x} = x^2 + (a+1) x + a + b + 1$$